# scale_x_discrete to show x-axis text with values

Tags: r

I have the following data in R:

```
dataframe = tibble(week = c(13, 16, 21),
                   amount = c(9, 9 , 19))


dataframe %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = week, y = amount,
               fill = week)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.75) +
    scale_x_discrete(
        limits = factor(1:52),
    )
```

In my plot on the x-axis, I would like to have my labels only show 1, 13, 16, 21, 52.
I can add the breaks = c(1, 13, 16, 21, 52) manually.  Is there a way I grab the week data in my data frame to automatically update the x-axis text?  I tried a few different but I kept getting errors and couldn't find an answer on google.  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does `breaks = c(1, dataframe$week, 52)` work?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thank you.  Follow up question, I have this data inside my dataframe so I use mutate to create the week column.  How can I use that created week column in the breaks?

Comment: You can encapsule your whole ggplot call in braces, that way, you can refer to the dataset by the magrittr dot `.`:
`... %>% {ggplot(data = ., aes(...)) + ... + scale_x_discrete(..., breaks = c(1, .$week, 52))}`